# How to print the result of calculation lua

Tags: lua

```
Local cl = rendom - or + 
Local a  = rendom number
Local x  = rendom number
Locol re = a..cl..x
Print (re) --output 5+8
```

I need to get the result 13

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the number 13 you can try:

```
Local cl = rendom "m" or "p" -- m for -, p for +
Local a  = rendom number
Local x  = rendom number
Local re = 0
if cl == "m" then re = a-x end
if cl == "p" then re = a+x end
Print (re) --output 13
```

or

```
Local cl = rendom "m" or "p" -- m for -, p for +
Local a  = rendom number
Local x  = rendom number
Local re = 0
if cl == "m" then re = a-x Print(a.."-"..x, re) end
if cl == "p" then re = a+x Print(a.."+"..x, re) end
```

Hope this helps!